# Função "Somarproduto" do Excel, não soma o total de dois itens distintos em relação a lista,?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Utilizei a função "Somarproduto" para somar o total dos produtos 1 e 2, mas o resultado da zero, queria somar o total dos valores de apenas dois produtos da lista, mas só funciona somando apenas um, como eu faço para aplicar a soma apenas nos produtos 1 e 2 ?? `=SOMARPRODUTO((A22:A38=A22)*(E22:E38)*(A22:A38=A23)*(E22:E38))` [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

> SOMARPRODUTO trata as entradas da matriz não numéricas como se fossem
>   zeros.
>   https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-somarproduto-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e

A tua coluna E "Valor R$" não é um valor numérico logo é considerado 0 e o resultado da multiplicação é 0.

Experimenta meter "100.0" em vez de "R$ 100.0"

Comment: Eu inseri em formato de número, mas ainda continua dando zero, mesmo apertando Ctrl + shift + enter

Comment: Teria algum jeito de somar o total desses dois produtos, utilizando apenas uma sequencia de fórmula?

Comment: Experimenta ```=SOMARPRODUTO(A22:A38,E22:E38)``` mantendo os valores como nº.

Comment: Não foi possível, por causa que tem que especificar o critério sendo apenas os produtos 1 e 2, que no caso daria o total da soma deles dois juntos

Comment: ```=PRODUCT(A22:A38)+PRODUCT(E22:E38)``` Experimenta assim. Tu não queres somar os valores das multiplicação de todos os elementos da coluna A e da multiplicação da coluna E?

Comment: Apenas os que estiverem com o "Cód.Produto" 1 e 2, só o que forem 1 e 2

Comment: `=SOMARPRODUTO((A4:A20=A4)*(E4:E20))+SOMARPRODUTO((A4:A20=A5)*(E4:E20))`  ou  apenas: `=SOMASE(A4:A20;A4;E4:E20)+SOMASE(A4:A20;A5;E4:E20)`

Comment: Não consegui com subtração, multiplicação e nem divisão, somente com soma, se tivesse subse, multse, divse, daria certo como na somase

Comment: Desculpa a demora. Tu queres a soma dos valores de todos da coluna que tenham o código do produto=1 ou 2?

Comment: Sim, mas eu já consegui aqui, fazer a soma e também a multiplicação somente dos produtos específicos. Agora eu pretendo fazer a subtração e divisão, mas até agora não descobri um jeito

Comment: Eu vou postar outra pergunta, agora como fazer a subtração e divisão